# Warning when loading Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

i'm getting this warning multiple times, but don't know the meaning.

```
03-03 15:16:37.155: W/ResourceType(13485): Failure getting entry for 0x010802c9 (t=7 e=713) in package 0 (error -75)
```

there is no other exception.

Comment: Please add a broader context (+- 10 lines of your LogCat output)

Comment: add some more information to your question.

Comment: the problem is, that there isn't any other message in log cat

Comment: nobody can tell me what this means?    0x010802c9 (t=7 e=713) in package 0? In the R the value isn't there.